# need assistance with some ruby array code, please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am making an app where `current_user` (logged in user) can write reviews, and make each review public or private,
 with a radio button.

If public, every other user can see that review. If private, only current_user can see it.

`visible.true` and `visible.false`, depending on which radio button is selected.

I'm trying to come up with the code/syntax to get this working?

Something like:

```
    #review.user is the person who wrote a particular review
    #if review.user is not current_user, and the review is
    #marked as false, then don't show that review
    If review.user != current_user
    && review.visible = false
    don't show review.
```

At present in a reviews_helper.erb I have:

```
  def review_block(review, options = {})
    options = {:review => review}
    render 'reviews/review', options
  end
```

And in my view, show.html.erb:

```
   <div class="reviews" >
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
      <%= review_block review %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Any chance you could tell me how I should modify my helper to get it working, or any other suggestions?

Comment: review.visible == false not review.visible = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you want to filter the `@reviews` array you could do something like this:

```
@reviews.select { |review| review.visible_to?(current_user) }.each do |review|
    render 'reviews/review', :review => review
end
```

The `Array`'s `#select` method filters a given array with the condition passed as block. I would move the visibility logic to the `Review` model to the method call `visible_to?` which would be something like you said above:

```
# review.rb
def visible_to?(user)
  self.user.id == user.id || # assuming they have an ID 
  visible == true
end
```

Better yet, if you are using Rails you can completely remove the `select` method call from the view and create a scope in the Review class.

Edit: Using a scope

```
 #review.rb
 scope :visible_to, lambda { |user| conditions( 'user_id = ? or visible = ?', user.id, true ) }
```

This way, when you are building your `@reviews` array - presumably in a controller action, you can do something like this:

```
 #reviews_controller.rb
 @reviews = Review.visible_to(current_user)
```

You can obviously nest several scopes - like order, limit, where, etc - and filter the review the way you want. Nevertheless the utility `visible_to?` method should also be defined for the instance itself alongside with the scope.

Always keep in mind to have your views as dumber as you can, i.e. your views should know the least about your models and your business logic. This will ensure there are no tight dependencies between your views and your models.

Comment: Tiago, you are a legend! Works perfectly. Not sure what you mean by creating a scope, will look into it, but your code works great. I've been working on this project for a year, at your rate it could be done in a week. Feel free to come here on holiday, we'll discuss rails, I'll pay your board and flight...It'll be cheaper for me, I swear!

Comment: Great! I didnt't check it though. As for scopes, they are part of the `ActiveRecord` framework and allow you to define a SQL filter as part of a `ActiveRecord` class and its resulting `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I'll edit my answer with a scope example.

Comment: Cheers again. I'm going to stick with the first for the time being, as I understand it better, but I know what you mean about keeping the View 'dumb' - I've commented in my code to refer back to the question in future. As for my reviews_helper.rb, which only contained the code in my question, I've simply deleted that file - my application works fine without it, it doesn't effect anything else. You think that's ok, or I should keep it, in case of implications down the line?